# Which pair of mathematicians has the most joint papers?

Tags: soft-question, sociology-of-math

I was searching on MathSciNet recently for a certain paper by two mathematicians.  As I often do, I just typed in the names of the two authors, figuring that would give me a short enough list.  My strategy was rather dramatically unsuccessful in this case: the two mathematicians I listed have written 80 papers together!

So this motivates my (rather frivolous, to be sure) question: which pair of mathematicians has the most joint papers?

A good meta-question would be: can MathSciNet search for this sort of thing automatically?  The best technique I could come up with was to think of one mathematician that was both prolific and collaborative, go to their "profile" page on MathSciNet (a relatively new feature), where their most frequent collaborators are listed, alphabetically, but with the wordle-esque feature that the font size is proportional to the number of joint papers.

Trying this, to my surpise I couldn't beat the 80 joint papers I've already found.  Erdos' most frequent collaborator was Sarkozy: 62 papers (and conversely Sarkozy's most frequent collaborator was Erdos).  Ronald Graham's most frequent collaborator is Fan Chung: 76 papers (and conversely).

I would also be interested to hear about triples, quadruples and so forth, down to the point where there is no small set of winners.

---

**Addendum**: All right, multiple people seem to want to know.  The 80 collaboration pair I stumbled upon is Blair Spearman and Kenneth Williams.

Comment: Who are the two mathematicians with 80 joint papers you found?

Comment: @OAC: For some reason I feel like revealing the names may spoil the fun for some.  But at the same time I worry that the sentiment of the previous sentence is obnoxious, so I clearly can't win on this one.  How about some hints: they are both Canadian algebraic number theorists, one in Prince George, the other in Ottawa.

Comment: The borwein brothers?

Comment: So people don't waste too much time checking MathSciNet - George Grätzer and E. T. Schmidt have 59 - Jaroslav Nešetřil and Vojtěch Rödl have 55 - Neil Robertson and Paul Seymour have 53 - Neil Hindman and Dona Strauss have 49 - Yuri Gurevich and Andreas Blass have 44.

Comment: It's evidently not a record, but Craig Tracy and Harold Widom have 44 in MathSciNet and I'm sure more in the pipeline.  (In MathSciNet, the Borweins only have 25.)


Comment: Though I don't mind the loss of reputation, I'm not sure why this was made community wiki.  This is a question with a unique correct answer...

Comment: Rather, it's most likely unique, and if not, at least there are only finitely many ties. :)

Comment: @James: In the case of a tie, the correct answer will be the complete list of pairs with the maximal number of joint papers. :)

Comment: Pure mathematicians speaking... As someone who takes interest in elections, let me offer a more practical maxim: "It's not the vote that matters, it's (the how of) the count".

Comment: @Victor:  "You know, comrades," says Stalin, "that I think in regard to this: I consider it completely unimportant who in the party will vote, or how; but what is extraordinarily important is this — who will count the votes, and how."

Comment: For a while, I thought Piatetski-Shapiro...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We get 135 matches for "Author=(Jimbo, Michio and Miwa, Tetsuji)" in mathscinet.

Comment: Impressive! $   $

Comment: Indeed.  $          $

Answer (score 16):

This is a frivolous item solely to demonstrate the pitfalls of running MathSciNet searches and working with large datasets:

Type "Wang and Zhang" in the author field and get a list of 2417 items. Li and Wang are close contenders with 2300 total. I wouldn't venture a guess how many collaborations that represents!

Comment: They must get up very early in the morning.

Answer (score 15):

How about Ravi Agarwal and Donal O'Regan with 445 joint journal publications on MathSciNet?

Comment: The citation indices for both authors is dramatic to say the least. (4677 and 3773 respectively.)

Comment: On a second count, there are 473 joint publications (needless to say that I didn't skim through them to check whether some of them were books rather than journal publications): http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=INDI&s1=23355%20and%20132880 .

Comment: It's funny, their papers have tons of citations from references, but very few from reviews. I guess maybe the mathematicians in this field don't have time to write detailed math reviews with references to previous work.

Answer (score 13):

> I.M.Gelfand and M.I.Graev: 119

**Disclaimer:** For the purposes of this answer, the paper count is the number given by MathSciNet, which includes book translations.

Comment: MathSciNet has separate listings for each edition of a book, and each translation of a book.
In this case, if you check Journals, you get 102 listings.
Although even this may have separate listings for each translation.



Comment: Ok, since you insist: 100 unique journal papers + 2 translations, 3 books + 6 translations, 8 proceedings papers --> 111 total

Answer (score 11):

Sergio Albeverio and Raphael Hoegh-Krohn have [98 papers together](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=INDI&s1=24435%2520and%252086835)
according to MathSciNet.

Comment: I took the liberty to link to the MathSciNet search result.

Comment: I had not heard of either of these mathematicians until now.  (I gather they work primarily on mathematical physics, a subject of which I remain ignorant, if not always blissfully so.)  Albeverio has written 696 papers, a figure which boggles my mind.  If I wrote one paper a month for 50 years, at the end I would be almost 100 papers short!  (I know there are a few mathematicians who have written significantly more papers than this, but this is already mind-boggling enough...)

Comment: This may depend on how you count! I an getting 98 joint publications, many with other people: (a) 10 books, including 2 re-editions and 2 translations, as well as 2 preprints published as articles (b) 58 journal articles; (c) 30 proceedings articles. Thus it is at most 92 (still impressive, but one fewer than Hardy and Littlewood).


Comment: @Pete: Leonard Carlitz's $\textit{Collected works}$ (hah!) is said to contain 6800 pages of research articles, http://turnbull.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Carlitz.html. That is, presumably, in addition to short notes and solutions to Monthly & Math Mag problems that he co-wrote. I should note that the vast majority of his 770 or 771 papers were written individually, although Carlitz and Scoville gives 42 items in MathSciNet(including "problems and solutions" and corrigenda).

Comment: @Pete:  Of course physics papers tend to have more authors than math papers, which means less writing for the average author.  And, in certain cases, the director of the lab (the one who got the funding) is listed as author on all papers produced there...


Comment: Well, Sergio is the most prolific and "collaborative" person I've ever met, so I immediately thought of him. Hoegh-Krohn passed away in 1988 at the age of fifty, otherwise the number would have been much higher. 

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps Hardy and Littlewood?

Comment: They seem like a strong contender, yes.  I avoided them above because I was doing a MathSciNet search, for which they are too early.  But the foreword to *Littlewood's Miscellany*, written by Bollabas, claims that they had 100 joint papers.  I would like to see an actual list, but I'm upvoting your answer for now.  (If this turns out to be the answer, what about mathematicians born after 1900?)

Comment: I think that Hardy & Littlewood have at most 93 joint papers
(I couldn't get the same count each time I tried in Hardy's
*Collected Papers*), so that seems to rule them out of contention.

Comment: Jahrbuch Database gives 93 papers, the last one being Notes on the theory of series. XX: Generalizations of a theorem of Paley,
Quart. J. Math. (Oxford Ser.) 8, 161-171. Published: 1937. I'd say that a series of 20 papers is in a league of its own.

Comment: Victor, a series of 20 papers is not quite unbeatable. The Robertson-Seymour series on the graph minor theorem is now up to "Graph minors XXIII" (to appear). And this is all around one theorem!

Comment: An honourable mention in this regard should go to Christopher Hooley, with his series of papers "On the Barban-Davenport-Halberstam Theorem". I believe this has now reached installment 17 at least.

One might also mention that Hooley is unlikely to be mentioned in the main discussion, being the author of 90ish papers on MathSciNet, all but one of which (an obituary) is single-author. Maybe I'll post this as a question...


Answer (score 8):

E. Cline, B. Parshall, and L. Scott have 28 papers together, spanning 35 years or so.  Just one example of a triple...

Comment: see also Giaquinta-Modica-Soucek, the famous Cartesian current triple (26 papers/books)

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that is surprisingly rare is a long term collaboration within a single math department. Erwin Lutwak, Gaoyong Zhang, and I, all at NYU-Poly, have a long term relationship that has yielded about jointly authored 21 papers so far, some with an additional author.